# How to ignore GUI as much as possible without rendering APP less GUI developer friendly

Tags: python, user-interface, portability

The substance of an app is more important to me than its apperance,  yet GUI always seems to dominate a disproportionate percentage of programmer time, development and target resource requirements/constraints.

Ideally I'd like an application architecture that will permit me to develop an app
using a lightweight reference GUI/kit and focus on non gui aspects to produce 
a quality app which is GUI enabled/friendly.

I would want APP and the GUI to be sufficiently decoupled to maximize the ease 
for you GUI experts to plug the app into to some target GUI design/framework/context.

e.g. targets such as: termcap GUI, web app GUI framework, desktop GUI, thin client GUI.

In short: How do I mostly ignore the GUI, but avoid painting you into a corner when I don't even know who you are yet?

Answer (score 3):

Write a core library that handles the functionality and provides hooks for progress notification. Then write the interfaces as separate applications or libraries that use the core library.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you seek is [MVC - Model/View/Controller.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)